# AngularJS location.path for custom URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

**Ctrl Code:**

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {

var o1 = $location.path();
var o2 = '/login';
var o3 = '/password-recovery';

if(o1.match(o2)){

  $scope.loginContainer= function() {
  return true;
};
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-show="loginContainer()">
 <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

The code works when url matches for `http://localhost/angapp/#/login` but now I have admin url's like below

```
http://localhost/angapp/#/admin/users
http://localhost/angapp/#/admin/usersGrp
http://localhost/angapp/#/admin/XYX
```

I need to use `var o4 = '/admin/';` so that it takes any url that starts with admin followed by moduleName and display html accordingly.

How do I make use of `location.path()` in order to match Admin URL's and show/hide div likewise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simplistic answer, but you can check if the url has the keyword "admin" in it and set a boolean variable to show or hide divs.

for eg:

```
    if ($location.absUrl().split('?')[0].match('admin')) {
        $scope.showDiv = true;
     } else {    
        $scope.showDiv = false;
    }
```

and the div can be

```
<div ng-show="showDiv"></div>
```

or

`<div ng-hide="showDiv"></div>`

But relying on url's is not the correct way to go if you want security, you might want to check out different ways for authentication and authorization, some links you may find useful are

1. https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/
2. http://www.stefanoscerra.it/permission-based-auth-system-in-angularjs/

Comment: Well, the question does not deals with security issues but how to set some navbar for user or admin end when url is changed. If I encounter admin, it will set admin header else user header.